# Can a Laser Engraver be used to develop PCB with photoresist?

Tags: pcb-fabrication, laser, etching

I'm building a simple laser engraver/cutter following these instructions:
http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1780556

Now my question is: can I use the laser light on the PCB photoresist instead of "*black master + UV neon*"?

I'm on early stage of building, and I have not bought laser yet. The instructions report "Laser: 1.6W Laser Diode 445nm (Basic Model) / 3.5W (Power-up Model)", so it's blue laser, but I may consider to buy another model if required to PCB photoresist.

Comment: Be the first to try and report

Comment: Please at least specify what type of laser you're using.

Comment: I added information in the main post.

Comment: https://youtu.be/4SNkzoOvoD8

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. What you need to know is the wavelength at which your photoresist absorbs the most energy. This should be specified in the corresponding datasheet of your manufacturer.

There are also commercial products which use laser diodes. I know of one that has 120 mW at 420 nm but different pcb manufacturers may use different photoresists which may require different wavelengths.

If you google Laser direct imaging you will find several commercial products.